# Identifying polynomials with other mathematical objects

Tags: polynomials

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to allow for the same manipulation of non-polynomial mathematical entities like matrices, linear transformations, differential operators, etc. as for polynomials?

For instance, if $T\in \mathcal{L} (V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{C}$, then for any $a_0,\ldots, a_m \in \Bbb{C}$, we can factor $$a_0I+a_1T+\cdots +a_mT^m\in \mathcal{L} (V)$$ as $$c(T-\lambda_1)\cdots (T-\lambda_m)$$ where $c=a_0$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_m \in \Bbb{C}$.

I’m mainly interested in the complex field where I can factor any polynomial entirely.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean in my opinion, could you state more precisely what you mean?

Comment: I’ve given an example now.

Comment: Commutativity of the nonscalar objects.

Comment: @jgon And? Cuz there should also be *integer powers* defined on these objects.

Comment: @Atom I was assuming that you were working inside some [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Comment: @jgon So can I say that **integer powers** *and* **commutativity** of theses objects along with **distributivity of these objects w.r.t. scalars and vice versa** are the necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: @Atom, it's not just integer powers, you need a full ring structure.

Comment: @jgon Can we have slightly weaker conditions? So that it’d be a necessary condition too.

Comment: "*allow for the same manipulation... as for polynomials*" is unanswerably imprecise, but the example suggests to me that it's not the question you intend to ask anyway. $a_0I+a_1T+\cdots +a_mT^m$ ***is*** a polynomial. I put it to you that the question you want to ask is "*What requirements must a set $S$ meet in order to meaningfully define polynomials over $S$ with coefficients from ring $R$*?" But maybe you want something stronger than just being able to meaningfully define them.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You just read my mind! But can we have weaker conditions on the set than being a *ring*?

Comment: Does there *have* to be commutativity to factorise them?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you're fixated on the ring part. All the examples you listed are rings, and taking the subring generated by a single element is always commutative. What's more, you'd have to be more precise about your question, but the way I was interpreting it, the answer is no. Nothing weaker will do. However, I may of course not be interpreting your question correctly.

Comment: You may find of interest closely related topics in constructive algebra such as factorization of differential and difference operators, e.g. see Petkovšek & Bronstein, [On Ore rings, linear operators and factorisation](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/68860/eth-3447-01.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)